# IE 8 issues (with js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Is there a way to tell a page/project this it should ignore some javascript code/file? I am working on a project, that works well on all browsers, eccept IE8. I haven't tested for less than IE8, and I wont bother. Anyway. The error that I am getting is my language, but I'll translate to English.

```
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 12204 in https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

0x800a01b6 - A javascript runtime error occured: The object doesn't support the property or method 'getElementsByClassName'

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued
```

This is just one of MANY errors like that. 
And many more. 
This is a huge problem for me. Is there any workaround for this? I am forced to keep this file, since the project is big, and other pages depend on this file

Comment: Please show the offending code that causes jQuery generate such an error. There is nothing inherently broken with jQuery 1.10 on IE8 - thus my initial conclusion is it's your code and must be argued otherwise.

Comment: where are you using `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: I second that. please show us the code which generated the error.

Comment: Is it just me or is the error pointing at the jQuery file from Google's API rather than OPs custom script? Kind of how Chrome shows this every time now `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, we want to know how and where the error is being created by the OP's code.

Comment: Depending on the size of OPs offending script and how many times it finds stuff by classname, this might not be easy.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Looks that way to me too. @@user: please don't use a minified version of a script for development. Use the non-minified jQuery so that we can see what's actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

You could try replacing this line...

```
getElementsByClassName("classname")
```

with...

```
$(".classname")
```